# Error "A database is required to access the back-end" when deploying to a remote server

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

On my local machine, I've developed a project with OCTOBER CMS. All good, I can go to backend cms and so on. When I'm deploying on a hosting server, everything is ok, except the backend cms. It keeps showing this to me:

> A database is required to access the back-end. Check the database is configured and migrated before trying again.

My `.env` file in that server has the changes of the database from the hosting server.

I've also tried to modify the `config/database.php` with the new credentials but without success.

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan cache:clear` ?

Comment: Or better yet: `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: `cache:clear` is for the cache store, not the configuration cache

Comment: none of the above works :(

Comment: @Anddres I just want to know if the issue has been resolved. I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Aaron yes, my problem was from the database config file. Make sure that you have all credentials ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are few  possible solutions to this:

- make sure the configuration is correct in file `config/database.php`
- make sure the database is created
- change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` if it didn't work
- clear the cache by running the command `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting up the db settings inside `config/database.php` file on SERVER?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with MySQL root not having remote access.
What I usually do is create a new user `'username'@'localhost'` and use those creds in my OCMS app. This has always worked for me.

Comment: can you tell me more how to do that?